# Having error when using blocks

Tags: ruby, syntax, block

I have a method taking a block, and I called it as follows:

```
def myfunc(symbol, args: nil, &block)
  ...
end

myfunc :user { p "BLOCK" }
#>> SyntaxError ((irb):19: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input myfunc :user { p "BLOCK" }
```

If I call the method using `do` ... `end` block style, it works.

What has been changed since Ruby 2.4, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Wrap the symbol argument - `myfunc(:user) { p "BLOCK" }`, otherwise there wouldn't be block being passed.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yes, that was it!